# How to solve the equation $Ln \bar{z}= \bar{Ln(z)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to solve the equation $\text{Ln}\,\bar{z}= \overline{\text{Ln}(z)}$  if Ln stands for the main branch value of the logarithmic function.

Please, help me. I really don't know what else to try. This is one of my multiple tries at this problem.
$$\text{Ln}\,\bar{z}= \overline{\text{Ln}(z)}\\
\ln |z| + i\arg z= \ln |z| - i\arg z\\   
\ln |z| = 1, \arg z=-1\\\implies |z|=e$$
$$w=\ln |z|\times e^{i\arg z}=e\times e^{-i}=e^{-i+1}$$

Comment: This is a true statement. For example, try $z=2+3i$

Comment: Please try to use Mathjax or Latex to write the question. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\ln \bar z  = \ln |z| + i\arg \bar z$ and $\arg \bar z \ne \arg z$ if $z$ is not real.

Comment: For any *real* analytic function $f$, it can be extended to a complex analytic function, In this case, that extension will always satisfy $f(\bar z) = \overline{f(z)}$ for all $z$, as long as any branch cuts are made along the real line, as the main branch of $\ln$ does.

Comment: What is the main branch?  The negative real axis?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "main branch" is the negative real axis, and $-\pi<\theta<\pi$, Then

$$\ln \overline{z} = \ln |z| - i \theta$$ and

$$\overline{ \ln z} = \ln |z| - i \theta,$$ so the solution is that $z$ is not on the branch cut:

$$ z \notin \{ x \le 0, y=0 \}$$